# How to perform segue inside unwind function

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have 3 MVCs and name them A, B, C here.

A is the main MVC with a button "Menu" connected to B with popover segue.

A also connected to C with a manual show segue.

B is a popover MVC with a button "Detail" connected to A with unwind segue.

C is the detail MVC with detail info.

Inside the unwind function of A. I call performSegueWithIdentifier to show C.

---

Expected behavior is

- Click "Detail" button in B
- B disappear and A show up
- C show up

---

But running the app I got.

- Click "Detail" button in B
- B disappear and A show up
- C show up
- C disappear and A show up

C show up and disappear suddenly which is not what I want.

---

Some additional info

- Popover B is needed for more buttons.
- A is embeded in a UINavigationController. Connecting A -> C rather than B -> C, for a Back button on top of C.

Answer (score 6):

Seems unwind function is not the correct place to call performSegueWithIdentifier.

UIKit will pop view controller *after* calling the unwind function.

Thus push new view controller inside unwind function will pop quickly.

The solution is to delay performSegueWithIdentifier.

Solution 1: *NOT WORKING FINE*

Adding an bool instance and inside viewDidAppear use this instance to determine if we perform segue.

Won't work if B controller is a popover. After B popover disappear, viewDidAppear is not called for A controller.

Solution 2: *WORKING*

Push performSegueWithIdentifier into main queue.

```
@IBAction func unwind(segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SomeSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect, this really helped me update my ui while performing segue in unwind function

Answer (score 0):

you can easily switch between the viewControllers by assigning storyboard id to them using below code ..

```
// you need to create UIStoryboard object by giving name of your storyboard
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
// here you need to create storyboard ID of perticular view where you need to navigate your app 
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewContIdentifire"];

// if use presentViewController this will not enables you to go back to previous view
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
                    **// OR**
// using pushViewController lets you to go back to the previous view
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Or still you want to work with segue so must gain control over them by implementing its delegate method below so they perform accordingly.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"]) {
        // perform segue
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:self]; 
    }
}
```

happy coding .. :)

Comment: Sorry, still don't know how to perform segue ***inside unwind function***.

Comment: you can work with storyboard id to switch between views using above section of code ..

Comment: Both pushViewController and performSegueWithIdentifier inside unwind function have same result. The C controller show up and disappear suddenly...