# how to handle rootviewcontroller in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

1. Hi, I am doing my first iOS application. I would like to know how to handle root view controller.
2. I have three view controllers for registration after register loading tabBar Controller in using storyboard (totally I added in storyboard only).
3. I am using only presenting view controller where have dismiss that view controller.
4. In appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions added `window.rootviewcontroller` my first view controller
5. How do I handle root viewcontroller in application

Comment: describe in more detail and share some code so can understand properly ..

Comment: after app delegate i am loading view controller  using                               [self presentViewController:XXXXXXXX animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: where have diss miss loaded view controller in app

Comment: if you want to get rootViewController you can get using `UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;`

Comment: @Piyush Patel :  i know  how to get root vie controller, where have to  dismiss loaded view controllers

Comment: any reason why down voted every ans here .. ?

Answer (score -1):

view controllers are loaded in stack and also behave like accordingly.
see below code and comments carefully or have a look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210092/4003548) ..this may help alot

```
// this takes your app to the root view controller
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

// this will takes you to the last view loaded in stack
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

// this takes to any view controller by using its identifire
[self.navigationController popToViewController:yourViewControllerName animated:YES];
```

Comment: @NagendarReddy welcome, may i know why down voted here ?